# How to simulate key press in java?

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String input = null;
while(true){
    input = br.readLine();
    if("".equals(input)){
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to wait 5 seconds and simulate enter-key press?

Answer (score 1):

1.- Wait 5 seconds:

```
    try 
    {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

2.- Press key event

```
     try
     {
             Robot robot = new Robot();
             robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
             robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
     } 
     catch (Exception exp) 
     {
             exp.printStackTrace();
     }
```

In this example enter is pressed. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) for the other keys

Hope that helps!

Comment: Maybe use the `robot.delay(5000);` instead of `Thread.sleep(5000);` to make it even simpler and you don't have to care about interrupts (:

Comment: @scsere Ohhh totally forgot about that, you're right. Thanks!